# Tunnel over ssh then through proxy to the internet

Tags: ssh, proxy, tunnel

I have a windows machine from which I can ssh into a unix machine with NX called 'London'. Here I can browse the web with firefox after I set the proxy to 'proxy3.com' and port 3128. At startup it asks for username and password I type it in and everything works fine.

The problem is that firefox is slow in NX so I thought it would be much better to tunnel to London and use a browser locally on my windows machine, but I don't know how to set up London to use proxy for this connection. I don't have root access to it, so I can't use export.

Answer (score 3):

Set up a tunnel in your SSH client, from a local port of [whatever really, let's say 31283] to remote proxy3.com:3128. Then in your local browser set proxy to localhost:31283.

When you ssh, all connections from local port of 31283 will go to proxy3.com on the remote side, therefore you'll be able to use that remote proxy locally.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I tried to simply ssh to proxy3.com from London with 'ssh proxy3.com -p 3128' but nothing happens. No prompt to give in username, no error and I have to cancel it with ctrl+c.

Comment: Hmm it seems like firefox not working even with manual proxy configuration, only with automatic proxy configuration with http://proxyconf.somecompany.com/, but there is nothing special in the pac file, for 'other sites' it returns 'proxy3.com'

Comment: No, it makes no sense to ssh into the proxy. You need to set up the tunnel when SSH-ing to your London host. I don't think NX allows setting tunnels, but since it's AFAIK a standard SSH connection you can use any other SSH client to set up a tunnel.